# How to deal with a disputed duplicate flag that is a real duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, disputed-flags

I have flagged this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50458050/date-format-of-json-php)
as duplicate. But when I was reviewing my flags I saw that it was disputed.

How could it be disputed that they're not duplicates when it clearly is?

Note: I flagged this in the triage review queue, I also didn't see any mention of how others reviewed this question as I was redirected to the next on queue.

Comment: Maybe it was disputed because of the JSON aspect of the new question?

Comment: But JSON is just a format and the answer can be applied directly to `$characters->instances[$i]->start`.

Comment: When you flagged the post, it was already in the [triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19794451) where three reviewers selected looks OK which set your flag as disputed.

Comment: Maybe so but I'm just providing a potential reason. I'm not saying that it isn't a dupe (or for that matter that it is).

Comment: @Script47 I thought of it the same way(JSON) but if you know what you're doing you'll realize that the answer can be applied to your code as well.

Comment: '*but if you know what you're doing*' - Could that be where the reviewers tripped up?

Comment: @SurajRao IMHO that would mean that they didn't bother searching for the question. I mean converting date to a human readable format is a very common question in SO. I should know as I always google it and find multiple results. :)

Comment: @Script47 They could probably be. I mean just searching [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=converting-datetime-to-a-human-readable-date+%5Bphp%5D) gives you a lot of results already.

Comment: Looks like it got invalidated by the [Triage queue review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19794451).  Makes no sense whatsoever of course.  That's a bug they'll probably won't fix.

Comment: It seems so. I mean they could hold on it for a while if there's an Unsalvageable flag on it. At the very least I now know why that flag was disputed. I didn't also know I can access that part of the triage.

Comment: @hungrykoala  The triage shows the only unsalvagable review from your username.. Out of curiosity, did you come across this question in the triage?

Comment: @SurajRao you mean the "looks ok" review of the others? No, I didn't. After I flagged it I was then redirected to the next question in the queue.

Comment: You might want to clarify the part that you flagged the post from the triage review queue and didn't arbitrarily go to the question.

Comment: @SurajRao Thank you for that. I'll do so right away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Why it happened

> How could it be disputed that they're not duplicates when it clearly
>   is?

Because the review consensus was not in your favor:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19794451

It entered Triage 6 hours ago. In there, it received 3 "Looks OK" votes, 2 "Needs editing" votes and 1 "Unsalvageable" vote (your duplicate flag).

Further, the post was reviewed as "No action needed" in the First posts review queue here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19794473

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253836/308386) is an explanation of how automatic disputing of closure flags works, in particular:

> This is a feature which is a part of the new Triage review queue. When
>   reviewers determine that the question Looks Ok and requires no further
>   action, the system automatically dismisses all pending non-custom
>   flags on the post as disputed - which includes recommend closure
>   flags. This is exactly what happened in your case.

### Further Steps

Since you can't cast close votes yet, if you strongly believe this question is a duplicate, your next recourse would be asking about it on meta (like you have done). Custom moderator flags should **not** be used for that purpose.

Comment: What is a custom moderator flag? I only know about flag for moderator attention. Are they the same?

Comment: @hungrykoala That'd be a flag for "needs moderator attention", yes. They're not to be used for pointing out duplicates.

Comment: @hungrykoala yes.. its custom because you can explain your reasoning

Comment: I agree with that. I think that flag should only be used in dire situations (Haven't encountered one yet that can't be flag as spam).

Comment: Triage being unhelpful as always, requires editing certainly wasn't the appropriate way to vote here either.