# First question duplicate flag disputed

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, new-users, disputed-flags

I have flagged [Why do I have a document.getElementById is Null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175109/why-do-i-have-a-document-getelementbyid-is-null) as a duplicate.

It's a first question and I really wasn't sure at first, if I should flag it or not because it might be discouraging for a new contributor to get the first question flagged. The question is nicely asked and a code snippet is provided.

**But**

> Why do I have a document.getElementById is Null?

was asked many times before e.g. here: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element), and it has a good and complete (community wiki) answer matching the problem (element.id spelling mistake) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14028960/8261024).

So the question is clearly a duplicate. It has two answers, telling OP exactly, where the typo is and providing working code snippets. To help keeping SO clean and usefull for future readers I decided to flag.

However my flag is shown as disputed in my flagging history.

On this post ([How to deal with a disputed duplicate flag that is a real duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368343/how-to-deal-with-a-disputed-duplicate-flag-that-is-a-real-duplicate)) is stated

> your next recourse would be asking about it on meta

So that's what I do. Should I refrain from flagging first posts or is there something else I overlooked?

Comment: As an aside to your first paragraph, flagging a question as a duplicate shouldn't ever be considered unwelcoming. When you provide the duplicate, you give the asker a place to find their answer immediately instead of waiting for an answer, you save people who were considering answering time when they realize they'd just be repeating things that are in another answer, and you help future readers find the most complete solutions all in one place. If someone gets upset that their question is closed as a good duplicate, then that's a problem with the person's expectations, not an issue with flags.

Comment: I can't see any indication in your review history that you ever reviewed that question. What exactly did you do? Could it be that you flagged and then choose skip? Or did you flag outside the review queue?

Comment: @BDL I flagged outside the review queue directly from the post.

Comment: As an aside. I just noticed you can vote to close as a duplicate or flag as a duplicate. It seems odd to me that both options are available. What's the difference?

Comment: @JeremyP If you can VTC, the flag is converted into a VTC.

Comment: This kind of thing bothers me sometimes, because "not finding" the element might not be immediately be the same to people as being null.  Just because the answer is the same doesn't mean the question is.

Comment: @dashnick I agree. The most difficult part in problem solving is always finding the right question to ask. I think, if duplicates are properly marked, searching will lead to the right question with the fitting answer.

Comment: At least your flag came to a conclusion. I have lost count on how many close votes as duplicates I cast just to know later they aged away.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You flag was set to disputed due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/22470892) Triage review where three user choose "Looks OK" and two "Requires Editing".

As explained in [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag/95277#95277):

> A recommend closure flag kicked the post into the Triage review queue, and the result of the review was "Looks OK" or "Needs Editing".

Nevertheless, your flag was imho correct and I added a close-vote to the question.

As @Davy M. already said in a comment, flagging a question as duplicate is not unwelcoming. It helps the question author to get their answer faster.

Comment: Does flagging as a duplicate not automatically produce the 'possible duplicate of ...' comment?

Comment: @JJJ: Yes it does. It is still there on the question. Why do you ask?

Comment: ah okay, I asked because if it didn't people in the review queue wouldn't even know it'd been flagged. And when going through the queue people may not realise it's a duplicate. Note also that the first review took place before the flag.

Comment: @JJJ 3 of 5 reviews took place after the flag. The question is, didn't they check the comments or didn't they agree? Note also, that all of them seem to be python experts with only a few or no javascript tags and when the first review took place, there were already two answers to the question.

Comment: @Olafant the answer is that we probably will never know.

Comment: @BDL The question is marked as duplicate now. I think that doesn't change my flag stats. But that's ok. Thanks for your answer and your voting.

Comment: All 5 of those reviewers should be warned/banned for robo-reviewing.